# Should I be wearing hearing protection when using a regular hammer?

Tags: tools, hand-tools, protection

When a hammer strikes an object, the kinetic energy of the hammer is rapidly deposited in the struck object and released all at once. I once read somewhere that this can cause a high impulse of sonic energy that may damage hearing. Is there any truth to this?

- **Should I be using hearing protection when using a regular old hammer?**
- What do safety standards have to say about this?
- Does the material I'm striking or the hammer material affect my required hearing protection?

---

In case anyone thinks I'm exaggerating, [here is a story](https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/979583605637877760.html) how someone dropped a ceramic toilet tank lid **a mere 8 inches** onto a toilet rim and damaged their hearing.

Comment: So why not do the equivalent calculations as those you have linked to and prove the situation with the hammer?

Comment: And are you wearing eye protection?

Comment: Yes, I certainly think so.  And yes, eye protection is more important.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, yes, hearing protection will reduce risk of hearing damage from any loud noise. It also has inconveniences, including possibly missing a quiet warning sound. There is no answer to "should I" without knowing all the details of your situation. I'm afraid this one is "use your own best judgement".

My approach tends to be that if I'm thinking about taking a protective action, I should probably be taking that action.

If your ears ring after a session of hammering, you would probably benefit from protection.

Then again my ears ring continuously for reasons that have nothing to do with loud noises, luckily at a frequency high enough that it is just annoying rather than actually affecting critical listening, so you might not want to consider me a good source.

Comment: "my ears ring continuously" also called tinnitus which is a result of past hearing damage

Comment: @ratchetfreak - There is not much agreement as to the cause of tinnitus.

Comment: Or more accurately, it's a symptom with multiple causes, and vulnerabilities differ.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a quiet ambient environment, sudden loud sounds such as striking a hammer can indeed cause a surprising amount of hearing damage. This answer is a bit of opinion, but I say yes, if using a hammer, I almost always wear hearing protection. Grabbing a pair of muffs is easy, and it's right near my hammers, so it's a no-brainer to use them.

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like you think it will create sonic boom. Which it won't. But, for prolonged hammering, I would recommend ear muffs.  It's all about dBAs.

You can't have standards for everything.  You have to use your own judgment.  If it is uncomfortable then use protection.

Comment: Check that story I linked. Dropping a ceramic toilet tank lid **a mere eight inches** onto a toilet rim causes (by that guy's calculations) 138 dB at 50 cm...

Are there any safety standards that say I should put on ear protection if I'm hammering more than 5 minutes or something? Can you prove hammers are safe to use without hearing protection?..

Comment: Define "safe". Ears age. Loud noise ages ears faster. Loud noises more frequently ages ears faster yet. Hammering is a middling loud noise, but a huge amount depends on what you are hammering, how close to your head, under what conditions, how often. There is no way to avoid the fact that life is eventually fatal; it's all about tradeoffs.

Comment: @Xunie, I am recommending that you use earmuffs.  So why do I have to prove hammering is safe?

Answer (score 0):

I wear hearing pro in many situations.  I'm not getting any younger, and neither are my ears.

It really depends on what you're doing—are you hammering a lot, or just banging in a couple of nails?  Are you doing this outside, or in a small enclosed space?

Your story about the toilet was probably exacerbated by the small space, which caused the noise to echo off the bathroom walls—possibly even a small "throne room," not a full bathroom.